# How to apply gravity to a projectile that has directional velocity?

Tags: javascript, physics, trigonometry, gravity, projectile

I have a bullet that fires at an angle. I want the bullet to 
react to a gravitational force.
The following code is in the update function of a bullet.

```
this.pos.x += Math.cos(this.angle * Math.PI/4) * (this.vel.x);
this.pos.y += Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI/4) * (this.vel.y);
```

This means that the bullet has been fired at `this.angle` which shouldn't change. The velocities should always be angled at `this.angle`.
The question now is: How do I add gravity?
Here is what I've tried so far.

The following code simply curves the bullet (down, but also up).

```
this.pos.x += Math.cos(this.angle * Math.PI/4) * (this.vel.x);
this.pos.y += Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI/4) * (this.vel.y);
this.vel.y += GRAVITY
```

I've also tried this:

```
this.pos.x += Math.cos(this.angle * Math.PI/4) * (this.vel.x);
this.pos.y += Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI/4) * (this.vel.y);
this.vel.y += Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI/4) * GRAVITY
```

The latter is the closest I've gotten to what I want it to do. However,
when `this.angle` is 0, `sin(0) is also 0`. This results in strange projectile misbehaviour when the angle is 0.

What are the best / conventional workarounds to this?

Comment: What is or isn't working?  Questions asking best practice/convention are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your position equation doesn't depend on the angle. You should only need the angle to initialize the vel.x and vel.y values.

You should have a normal speed and do initialize them with

```
var bulletSpeed = 100;
this.vel.x = Math.cos(this.angle)*bulletSpeed;
this.vel.y = Math.sin(this.angle)*bulletSpeed;
```

Then update the values with

```
this.pos.x += this.vel.x;
this.pos.y += this.vel.y;
this.vel.y += GRAVITY
```

This doesn't use gravity as an acceleration though since there's no time variable from what I can tell

Comment: Thank you! This helped me! Instead of time I updated the acceleration in a third vector, and it works like I want it to now!

Answer (score 1):

is there some variable for time? if so then

`this.vel.y += GRAVITY * time`

might work